# ¿Como copiar datos de un archivo (.txt) a una estructura en C?

Tags: c

Hace poco me dejaron un proyecto en el que debo crear una estructura con ciertos campos y dentro de un archivo de texto va lo siguiente:

12345,andres,gonzalez,100

65432,pedro,contreras,150
.......................

Una cantidad N de lineas con 4 palabras en cada separadas por ",". Lo que mi programa debe de hacer es ir leyendo linea por linea y cada palabra separada por la "," va en un campo de la estructura. Yo logré escribir un poco de código el cual si me guarda los datos pero solamente lee la primera linea. La estructura la estoy manejando como un vector. El resultado esperado sería:

**LA PRIMERA LINEA SI LA GUARDA**

usuarios[0].CardId = 12345

usuarios[0].name = andres

usuarios[0].surname = gonzalez

usuarios[0].funds = 100

**NO LEE LAS DEMÁS LINEAS PERO DEBERÍA QUEDAR ASÍ**

usuarios[1].CardId = 65432

usuarios[1].name = pedro

usuarios[1].surname = contreras

usuarios[1].funds = 150

No logro hallar el error en mi código el cual impide que salte de línea. Si alguien podría decirme que error cometí o bien una mejor manera estaría muy agradecido.

```
struct usuarios {
    char CardId[30];
    char name[30];
    char surname[30];
    int funds;
};

void NewData(struct usuarios personas[3]){
    struct usuarios regTemp;
    FILE *stream = fopen("accounts.txt","r");
    char *tem;
    char cc;
    if(stream == NULL){
        printf("Error en la apertura del archivo \n");
    } else{
        char ca[250];
        int c = 0,per = 0;
        fgets(ca,255,stream);
        while(feof(stream) == 0){
            cc = fgetc(stream);
            tem = strtok(ca,",");
            while (tem != NULL){
                switch (c){
                    case 0:
                        strcpy(regTemp.CardId,tem);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        strcpy(regTemp.name,tem);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        strcpy(regTemp.surname,tem);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        regTemp.funds = atoi(tem);
                        break;
                }
                c++;
                tem = strtok(NULL,",");
            }
            personas[per] = regTemp;
            c = 0;
            per++;
            fgets(ca,255,stream);
        }
        fclose(stream);
    }

}
```

Comment: @Juanjo Eso no tiene nada que ver. Si la función `fclose()` estuviera adentro del `while`, ahí sí estaría mal, pero en este caso no. Al parecer el problema no es la función, ya que a simple vista se ve que el código está bien. Entonces lo más probable es que esté imprimiendo los datos después de la invocación de `NewData` y como lo paso por valor, todos los datos que había recogido en la función, se perdió.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tengo varias dudas respecto al código proporcionado pero intentaré explicarte lo que creo que está pasando:

```
 fgets(ca,255,stream);
```

Con esto almacenas los promeros 255 caracteres del fichero o los que hayan hasta encontrar EOF o un salto de linea, esto desplaza el puntero del stream lo mas seguro es que no te detecte los saltos de linea (algo que me ha ocurrido mucho usando fgets) y lea los 255 caracteres. Como tu fichero tendrá menos caracteres llegará a EOF en la primera iteración.

Te recomiendo revisar el formato del fichero, pero te voy a explicar un poco como lo  haría yo:

```
while((fgetc(stream)!=EOF)||(per==MAX)){//hasta que se alcanza el maximo de personas o se llega a EOF
do{
i=0;
while((tem[i]=fgetc(stream))!=','){//almacena los caracteres que encuentre hasta una coma
   printf("%c",tem[i]); //se comprueba que se guardan correctamente
i++;
}
tem[i]='\0';//se limpia el ultimo caracter, de otro modo la coma tambien se guardaría
...    
//crearía el campo correspondiente con tu estructura de switch case
...
tem[0]='\0'; // una vez introducido el campo correspondiente "vacias" tem
c++; //incrementaria el numero del campo a crear
}while(fgetc(fp)!='\n');//cuando el siguiente caracter sea un salto de linea se pasa al siguiente usuario
per++;
}
```

Tendrías que darle ciertas modificaciones al código puesto que exactamente no se como tienes el formato del fichero, pero de primeras este codigo te serviría para un fichero de esta forma.

12345, andres , gonzalez, 100,

65432, pedro, contreras, 150,

Comment: Si pruebas el código del OP con el siguiente formato: `12345,andres,gonzalez,100`, funciona correctamente. Ahí se ve claro que el problema no esté en el `fgets`. Falta que el OP indique como recorre el *array* de estructuras.